# Non commutative ring of order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{F_2}: = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be the field with two elements and consider the ring $R$ = $M(2,\mathbb{F_2})$ of 2 x 2- matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{F_2}$.

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ be two matrices in $R$. Let $O$ bet the zero matrix.

Let $S=\{O, A, B, A + B\}\subset R$.

If we write $+s$ and $*s$ for the induced maps

$+s$ : $S$ $*$ $S$ $\rightarrow$ $R$

$*s$ : $S$ $*$ $S$ $\rightarrow$ $R$

I have to show that $*s$ is contained in $S$ and using that I have to show that ($S, +s, *s$) is a non- unitary, non- commutative ring of order 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to find out $A^2$, $B^2$, $AB$ & $BA$ and use $2=0$.

Comment: I calculated those 4 different matrices but what should I do next?

Comment: Then you can see that the set is closed under multiplication and it is clearly closed under addition. Write the multiplier table to confirm that there is no identity element and $AB \neq BA$ So non-commutativity follows

Comment: I do not get the right multiplier/Cayley table... Is there a possibility you can write it out? It would really help me

Comment: You don’t actually need the Cayley table you can see either of $A$, $B$ are not identity as $AB \neq BA$ and $(A+B)^2=O$ and $O$ is trivially not identity.